# Client sent me his distribution certificate and private key so I can push to the Appstore, but they don't associate with themselves

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, certificate

Been pulling my hair all morning over this, we've got a client that has his own credentials for distribution. I downloaded the AppStore provisioning profile associated with the appID in his provisioning portal and also downloaded his distribution certificate from there.

Since I can't sign until I have a valid cert/private key pair, I asked him to export his so that I can import it into my keychain. However, when I imported the resulting p12, instead of associating itself with the certificate, it went on and created a new self-signed root certificate and the private key associated itself with it.

Confused, I tried to export one of my own unused private key, delete it and imported it and it correctly went under the associated certificate (a push notification certificate). So I asked him if he exported the correct private key. He assures me he did, and even went on and exported both the certificate and the key for me.

The certificate he issued me is correctly the one I downloaded in his portal, but the p12 is still not associating itself with the certificate! I don't know what I'm doing wrong... anyone have clue/lead on this?

Comment: just revoke present certificate and then make new certificate...then import in and use p12 certificate on your computer..

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that's the problem, and anyway asking to revoke the certificate is very drastic. I won't ask the client to revoke his perfectly working certificate and remake all his provisioning profiles just because I can't correctly import his private key. But I do appreciate the suggestion, thank you!

Comment: are you downloading fresh certificate from apple or client sending p12

Comment: Tried downloading the distribution certificate from his provisioning portal (on apple.developer), imported that cert and asked for his private key in p12 form. Since that didn't work he tried sending me both his private key in p12 form and the associated certificate from his keychain (which was the same from the one I downloaded in the portal). Both times the p12 didn't associated itself with the certificate, it went on and placed itself under a new self-signed root certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them follow the instructions here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/export_signing_assets.html

- In the Devices organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
- Click Export.
- Specify a filename and a password, and click Save.

The yourself, follow the instructions here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH9-SW1

- In the Devices organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
- Click Import.
- Select the file containing your code signing assets.
- Enter the password for the file, and click Open.

Now, that's the *theory* anyways. When you do this there is an error in iOS when importing the file. I ran into this myself. Apparently it's been broken since 2009. The solution is to import manually from the command line. You need both the .p12 and the .pem files previously exported from your client.

To export the .p12 (private key) and .pem (public key):

- Open Keychain Access
- Select "login" keychain (or whichever is appropriate)
- Select "Keys" category at the bottom
- Select private key "iOS Developer: name here" (Or in case of distribution profile, whichever name appears on the distribution certificate)
- Right click and select Export (this is your .p12 file)
- Select public key "iOS Developer: name here" (Or in case of distribution profile, whichever name appears on the distribution certificate)
- Right click and select Export (this is your .pem file)

Then you need to manually import them into your keychain:
http://www.arlt.eu/blog/2009/12/01/importing-iphone-keys-p12-and-pem-into-snow-leopards-keychain/

```
security import priv_key.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

After that is done, you will have all you need to sign the app using their distribution certificate (which you can download from developer center)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already shot him an email asking him to export the developer profile via Organiser about 20 mins ago, which is pretty much the steps you explain in the organiser. I'm not sure I understand the part where you import manually though, since the resulting file from the export is a .developerprofile not a .p12 and a .pem

Comment: @PhilippeBoivin, I've added the extra steps for exporting .p12 and .pem that your client should execute. The .developerprofile should have been a one-click solution, but as you can see, it's broken. Hope this helps

Comment: The developerprofile steps were enough, it worked for me. Thanks!